# Remove duplicate rows from pandas dataframe using specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know there are lot of questions about removing duplicates from pandas dataframe but this is bit different.

I am trying to remove duplicates from the dataframe but not getting the actual output as in the below given result dataframe. Actually the data in table is too long. For understanding purpose I have given the dummy data here in the table.

**Condition:-**

I need to remove duplicates and get the rows that contain max value from **diast** column.

Is there a good way to get result dataframe using given df.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

**DF:-**

| age | syst | diast | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 90 | 57 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |
| 29 | 90 | 58 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |
| 29 | 90 | 59 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |
| 29 | 90 | 60 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |
| 29 | 90 | 61 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 29 | 90 | 62 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 29 | 90 | 63 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 29 | 90 | 64 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 29 | 90 | 65 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |
| 29 | 90 | 66 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |
| 29 | 90 | 67 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |
| 29 | 90 | 68 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |

**Result:-**

| age | syst | diast | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29 | 90 | 60 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |
| 29 | 90 | 64 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 29 | 90 | 68 | MO | MO | 0 | MO |

Comment: what is the specific condition, please add that as part of your question

Comment: Please see the updated question. I need to get the result dataframe using given df.

Comment: why you get the diast 60, first row? shouldn't that be removed too

Comment: No, that should not be removed. That's why I need a help how to do this.

Comment: posted the answer, does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this:

```
df['id']=df.groupby(['age', 'syst', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).ngroup()
df['id2']=df['id'].shift(-1)

df2=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['age', 'syst', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd','id','id2'],keep=False).drop(['id','id2'],axis=1)
print(df2)
'''
    age  syst  diast   a   b  c   d
3    29    90     60  MO  MO  0  MO
7    29    90     64   0   0  0   0
11   29    90     68  MO  MO  0  MO
'''
```

Comment: First, I removed the **diast** column and grouped the remaining columns among themselves and gave each group an id. In your example, we have 3 groups. I then assign the value of these ids from the previous row in a new column. If id and id2 are different, it means that it has moved to a new group. Finally, we left all the same values ​​except for **diast**. As a result, we got the expected output. **NOTE**: you may need to sort the **diast** column if different results come out.

Comment: What keep=False does?

Comment: its drop all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
# create a flag to separate out the group based on column 'a'
# a is the only column that distinguishes the group
df['flag'] = np.nan
df['flag']=df['flag'].mask(df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()), 1).cumsum().ffill()

# sort, drop duplicates, keep flag as one of the column
# finally drop the flag column
(df.sort_values(['age','syst','diast'])
 .drop_duplicates(subset=['age','syst', 'a','b','c','d','flag'], keep='last')
 .drop(columns='flag'))
```

```
    age     syst    diast   a   b   c   d
3    29     90         60   MO  MO  0   MO
7    29     90         64   0   0   0   0
11   29     90         68   MO  MO  0   MO
```